# Is it possible app "restarts" when it is suspended?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Sometimes user moves to other app, i.e. to browser, and when returns to app, app do not show the latest screen, because it seems it has restarted. Is it possible? Users states it happens.

Comment: Yes,  a suspended app can be terminated if the system needs memory. You can opt in to [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches/about_the_ui_restoration_process)

Comment: How can I know app was terminated by user on purpose or was terminated because system needed memory?

Comment: You can't really; in most cases where iOS terminates your app, `applicationWillTerminate` will be called, while it won't if the user terminates the app

Comment: Additionally you can try to handle OOM (out of memory) event in the app delegate, which happens before the app termination because system needs memory. Not sure will work though ) Just an idea.

Comment: As @CynichniyBandera says, returning memory when the low memory condition occurs will make iOS consider other Background apps (that don't cooperate with the request) before yours for termination. However this will only reduce the probability of termination - inevitably your app will terminate sometimes and you need to manage that.

Comment: I did not mean to release some memory in OOM handler, it is often nothing to release. My idea was just because of the fact that the app was asked to release memory, the probability of being killed is getting higher. Not much though, because others, especially heavy apps, could really release some memory and defer killing someone.